How to declare global variables in Blazor
How to declare global variables in Blazor , for example I have inputquestions in Index I want to use this in another page called Quiz.
https://github.com/KalyanAllam/MauiAppMCQs/
@page "/"
<h1>  Quiz </h1>
Select Input Questions and 
Click on  Quiz  .
<div class="row">
    <p>Questions:</p>
    <input type="range" min="5" max="20" step="5" @bind="@inputquestions"
     @bind:event="oninput" />
</div>
<p>@inputquestions</p>
@code {
    public  int inputquestions=5;
}



Global variables on a Website is usually not a really smart choice, because all instances share this value...

Be aware that any "global" stuff is for "all users".
What "all users" means heavily depends on interactivity mode you choose.

Blazor wasm (and maui): Your static class or singleton is for the one user only and you are safe to use both
Blazor Server (and SSR): Don't use static classes and singletons for keeping user related data.

Static classes
public static class MyStaticClass
{
  public int InputQuestions {get;set;} =5;
}

<input type="range" min="5" max="20" step="5" @bind="@MyStaticClass.InputQuestions"
     @bind:event="oninput" />


Or a service
public MyClass
{
public int InputQuestions {get;set;} =5;
}

//program.cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyClass>();


@inject MyClass myClass
...
@bind="@myClass.InputQuestions"

For a difference between these two, look for Singleton vs Static class

Please note that a Singleton in Blazor-Server means all users share the same Instance. Same for a Static Class. In Blazor-Wasm it is the same Instance for the one user that is using the app.

@jeb well, that's true. I had my mind "locked in" blazor wasm, where these consideration disappear. I will edit the answer.

@Alamakanambra I did above changes here is source code by two-way binding doesn't seem to work. It is always passing 5 to next page even I change it to 10 or 15 ,here is my source code https://github.com/KalyanAllam/MauiAppMCQs/

@KALYANAALLAM The binding works and the value gets to the myClass, right? Where is the other usage of your MyClass. Because I don't see any in your code. Only in your QuizCardBase.cs wher you initialize (= new MyClass()) the variable again (not getting the one from the DI container)...

@Alamakanambra I want to use myClass in QuizCardBase.cs.I am initializing the variable (= new MyClass())   as its throwing's null reference , please suggest how do I get from DI container
if (count == myclass.InputQuestions)
{ stopflag = "N"; }

I tried to use Route parameter it worked
